# Is there a way to get a class name in php, convert it into a string and store it in a variable?

Tags: php, oop

I have a class Bar with a method saveToTable($table), I need to have a default value for $table but that value needs to be dynamic, the dynamic value should be the name of the class Bar is extending to.

```
class Bar {

  public function saveToTable($table) {

  }

}



class Foo extends Bar {

}

$bar = new Foo;

$bar->saveToTable(); // in which case saveToTable() would have a param of 'foo' i.e. saveToTable('foo');
```

The solution I am using at the moment is explicitly specifying a $table property inside every class that extends Bar and assign it a string value of those classes' names, but this would defeat the purpose of making my app dynamic, plus it would be pretty cumbersome and prone to errors.

Comment: This is really bad design. Don't mix business logic with implementation details like the name of the class.

Comment: ok, i see, so what would you suggest then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using a parameter with default value for your method (wich can't be assigned dynamically)
consider using somethig like this:

```
class Bar {

    protected $classname;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->classname = static::class;
    }

    public function saveToTable() {
        echo $this->classname;
    }
}
```

Now inside saveTotable() you have your class name as string.

```
class Foo extends Bar {

}

$bar = new Foo;

$bar->saveToTable(); // will echo 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) which will reference to extended class

add this method to your `Bar` class

```
 class Bar{

   public function getClassName()
   {
      return static::class;
   }
 }
```

and now you can get the name

```
$bar = new Foo();

$bar->getClassName(); // returns Foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, take care about namespaces, maybe you need delete

```
class Bar
{
    public function saveToTable()
    {
        //Without namespace
        $table = substr(static::class, strlen(__NAMESPACE__) + 1);
        //With namespace
        $table = static::class;
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar
{
}

$bar = new Foo;
$bar->saveToTable();
```